# Reasoning about the PDF of fair dice rolls from the definition $P(X \in A) = \int_\mathbb{R}1_Af_Xd\Lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Unfortunately, I haven't yet had the time to dig deeper into pure measure theory, so I get easily baffled by simple questions like these. For example, we know that if $X$ is an r.v. representing rolls on a fair six sided dice, then $P(X = z) = \frac{1}{6}$ for any $z \in \{1,2\dots,6\}$. Given this information, can we then conclude that $X$ has a probability density function $f_X$ in the sense that for all Borel sets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ it holds true that $P(X \in A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}1_Af_Xd\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure? What confuses me in this setting is that the Lebesgue measure of any countable set is zero, so if, say $A = \{1\}$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_Af_Xd\Lambda = \int_{\{1\}}f_Xd\Lambda$, but $P(X = a) = \frac{1}{6}$.

I am asking this question because usually one would be given a summation instead of integration when the r.v.s are discrete, the density function is defined as an integral above with Lebesgue measure in my reading material.

Comment: Discrete r.v.'s $X$  have no density function $f_X$ and your $X$ is discrete,.

Comment: Your $X$ has what is called a pmf (Probability Mass Function) but it has no density.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. So it would be valid to state that $X$ is a real valued r.v. which does not have a density function?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, $X$ does not have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure. However, we always find a base measure $\mu$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \int 1_A f_X d\mu$.  In this case, $\mu$ would be the counting measure (not Lebesgue measure).

In general, the precise type of density you're probably thinking about is called a Radon-Nikodym derivative. We can find a density $f_X$ with respect to the base measure $\mu$ if and only if the probability measure induced by $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, meaning that for all sets $B$ such that $\mu(B) = 0$, $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = 0$. In your example, this is not true since we could take $B = \{1\}$ and then if $\mu$ were Lebesgue measure, $\mu(B) = 0$ but $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = 1/6$. See the wikipedia page for Radon-Nikodym derivatives for more specifics.

Edit: in case it's helpful, in this case the density of $X$ would be $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{6} 1_{x \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}}$ and the base measure is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. This is also known as the probability mass function. (Roughly speaking, probability mass functions are just densities with respect to an underlying measure which is not the Lebesgue measure, such as the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$.)